# My project's iOS deployment target is set to iOS 9.0 and i want to integrate Reality Kit in my app for iOS 13.0 and up

Tags: ios, xcode, crash, augmented-reality, realitykit

**RealityKit** is only available on *iOS 13.0* and up and when I try to integrate it to my project and run it on *iOS 12.0* or below, the app crashes with `abort_with_payload` error.

I still want my app to run on *iOS 9.0* - *iOS 12.0* without the AR feature. Is there a way I can do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This happens because the framework `RealityKit` always imports even though the device does not have that framework. The solution is to make it optional based on the device you are using.

1. Go to you project's `Build Settings`.
2. Go to `Linking` -> `Other linker Flags`
3. Double click `Other linker Flags` values to add a new one.
4. Press add button then type `-weak_framework RealityKit`

That should do it. Enter then run your app.

Hope this helps. Happy Coding. :D

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the `canImport(module)` directive

```
#if canImport(RealityKit)
    import RealityKit
#endif

@available(iOS 13.0, *)
class MyClassWhichUsesRealityKit {

  func do() {
      let v = ARView(frame: .zero)
  }
}
```

Source: https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0075-import-test.md